# How do I setup wfetch to send data to an HTTPS site?

Tags: iis

Why do I keep get this error when I use `wfetch` to connect to HTTPS sites?

```
0x80090329 (The specified data could not be encrypted.): [slib]: SealMessage
```

her is my log and my input body(input from base64 image encoded to string):
Accept: */*\r\n
Content-Length:16437\r\n
Authorization: Basic bnBheWFwcDpucGF5YXBw\r\n
\r\n
0x80090329 (The specified data could not be encrypted.): [slib]: SealMessage0x80090329 (The specified data could not be encrypted.): Error On 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

Comment: Improved formatting/spelling for readability

Comment: You need to post a screen shot at least.

Comment: sory i cannot post screen shot my reputation still 8